# replace the random value of a stock chart with historical data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to replace the data in the table with data from google finance or yahoo finance. The data must start at 2017-01-01 since the current day. How can i replace those object with other objects containing information formatted in this way? Please give me a hand, I need the piece of code in a short time for school motives.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
  // Set the data.
  table = anychart.data.table('x');
  table.addData([
    {'x': '2015-04-01', 'o': 18.23, 'h': 19.36, 'l': 18.18, 'c': 19.31},
    {'x': '2015-04-02', 'o': 19.50, 'h': 19.89, 'l': 19.00, 'c': 19.29},
    {'x': '2015-04-03', 'o': 19.13, 'h': 19.15, 'l': 18.43, 'c': 18.75},
    {'x': '2015-04-06', 'o': 18.54, 'h': 18.76, 'l': 18.27, 'c': 18.76},
    {'x': '2015-04-07', 'o': 18.76, 'h': 19.14, 'l': 18.63, 'c': 18.76},
    {'x': '2015-04-08', 'o': 18.97, 'h': 19.62, 'l': 18.96, 'c': 19.19},
    {'x': '2015-04-09', 'o': 19.45, 'h': 19.70, 'l': 19.22, 'c': 19.67},
    {'x': '2015-04-13', 'o': 19.69, 'h': 19.85, 'l': 19.37, 'c': 19.59},
    {'x': '2015-04-14', 'o': 19.44, 'h': 19.55, 'l': 19.00, 'c': 19.35},
    {'x': '2015-04-15', 'o': 19.21, 'h': 19.25, 'l': 18.51, 'c': 18.83},
    {'x': '2015-04-16', 'o': 19.16, 'h': 19.78, 'l': 18.99, 'c': 19.76},
    {'x': '2015-04-17', 'o': 19.69, 'h': 19.69, 'l': 19.00, 'c': 19.20},
    {'x': '2015-04-20', 'o': 18.89, 'h': 18.95, 'l': 18.57, 'c': 18.61},
    {'x': '2015-04-21', 'o': 18.59, 'h': 19.08, 'l': 18.57, 'c': 18.97},
    {'x': '2015-04-22', 'o': 18.76, 'h': 19.19, 'l': 18.70, 'c': 18.78},
    {'x': '2015-04-23', 'o': 18.92, 'h': 18.94, 'l': 18.47, 'c': 18.92},
    {'x': '2015-04-24', 'o': 19.82, 'h': 21.20, 'l': 19.50, 'c': 20.91},
    {'x': '2015-04-27', 'o': 20.55, 'h': 20.82, 'l': 20.28, 'c': 20.40},
    {'x': '2015-04-28', 'o': 20.25, 'h': 20.27, 'l': 19.79, 'c': 19.93},
    {'x': '2015-04-29', 'o': 20.11, 'h': 20.89, 'l': 20.06, 'c': 20.25},
    {'x': '2015-04-30', 'o': 20.60, 'h': 21.10, 'l': 20.01, 'c': 20.26},
    {'x': '2015-05-01', 'o': 20.19, 'h': 20.35, 'l': 19.86, 'c': 20.24},
    {'x': '2015-05-04', 'o': 20.37, 'h': 20.40, 'l': 19.98, 'c': 20.19},
    {'x': '2015-05-05', 'o': 20.14, 'h': 20.24, 'l': 19.64, 'c': 19.79},
    {'x': '2015-05-06', 'o': 20.06, 'h': 20.07, 'l': 19.61, 'c': 19.79},
    {'x': '2015-05-07', 'o': 19.96, 'h': 19.99, 'l': 19.14, 'c': 19.32},
    {'x': '2015-05-08', 'o': 19.46, 'h': 19.64, 'l': 19.14, 'c': 19.42},
    {'x': '2015-05-11', 'o': 19.20, 'h': 19.73, 'l': 19.01, 'c': 19.32},
    {'x': '2015-05-12', 'o': 19.51, 'h': 20.06, 'l': 19.47, 'c': 19.89},
    {'x': '2015-05-13', 'o': 19.92, 'h': 20.00, 'l': 19.67, 'c': 19.75},
    {'x': '2015-05-14', 'o': 19.83, 'h': 20.23, 'l': 19.80, 'c': 20.06}
  ]);

  // Map the data.
  mapping = table.mapAs({
    'open': "o",
    'high': "h",
    'low': "l",
    'close': "c"
  });
  chart = anychart.stock();

  // Set the series.
  var series = chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping);
  series.name("ACME Corp. stock prices (apr 2015 - jul 2015)");

  chart.title('Generali');
  chart.container('container');

  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.14.0/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.14.0/anychart-ui.min.css" />

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: have a look at *AJAX* ( http://jquery.com will help ) and find out the correct REST API...

Comment: I think I have to use a YQL query, but I did not understand how it works.